# glfw3 specific refrences missing with glfw3

Tags: c++, glfw

when I had tried to compile the example code for glfw3 on http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html (copy/pasted to test compilation), I got the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccCdEKoi.o: In function main':
example.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference toglfwCreateWindow'
example.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to glfwMakeContextCurrent'
example.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference toglfwWindowShouldClose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling with `g++ example.cpp -o example -lGL -lglfw` and when I installed the latest glfw 3.0.2, it installed without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLFW3 builds as `libglfw3` by default, not `libglfw` as GLFW2 did.  So you're probably still linking against your GLFW2 installation.

Solution:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -lGL -lglfw3
```

Comment: if I do this, this will give me a slew of X11 related errors. I think i fixed this once with some googling before, so I'll try to re-google the errors. There wern't too many results but one did fix it.

Comment: X11 related errors sounds like you're linking statically to GLFW.  I'm using `-lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lrt -lXrandr -lXi` to do this successfully.